# Generate missing dates from json and store in to array using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have one date range json and I need to generate missing dates and store into an array but how can I do have no idea.

Here below json:

```
var availabilityJson = 0:{ Status : 1 
    DateFrom : "2018-08-22 00:00" 
    DateTo   : "2018-08-24 00:00" }
1:{ Status : 1 
    DateFrom : "2018-10-01 00:00" 
    DateTo   : "2018-11-30 00:00" }
2:{ Status : 1 
    DateFrom : "2018-12-15 00:00" 
    DateTo   : "2018-12-31 00:00" }
```

So above from the json missing date range is 2018-08-25 to 2018-09-30. so I need to generate missing dates like this **2018-08-25,2018-08-25,...,2018-09-30,2018-12-01,...2018-12-14** and store into an array.

I have tried like this to generate missing dates but how can take 2 objects and generate missing dates.

```
var UnAvailable = $.grep(availabilityJson, function (object, index) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have to get success and missing dates generated.

Here below I have done like this code.

```
var startDateForFirstObject;var availabilityDates = [];
                var missingDatesForCustomeBoats = $.grep(availabilityJson, function (object, index) {                                              
                        var end = new Date(object.DateFrom);
                        if (index != 0) {                               
                            while (startDateForFirstObject < end) {
                                var day = (new Date(startDateForFirstObject).getDate().toString().length === 2 ? new Date(startDateForFirstObject).getDate() : "0" + new Date(startDateForFirstObject).getDate());
                                var monthIndex = ((new Date(startDateForFirstObject).getMonth() + 1).toString().length === 2 ? (new Date(startDateForFirstObject).getMonth() + 1) : "0" + (new Date(startDateForFirstObject).getMonth() + 1));
                                var year = new Date(startDateForFirstObject).getFullYear();
                                var fullDate = year + "" + monthIndex + "" + day;
                                availabilityDates.push(fullDate);
                                startDateForFirstObject.setDate(startDateForFirstObject.getDate() + 1);
                            }
                        }
                        startDateForFirstObject = new Date(object.DateTo);
                        startDateForFirstObject.setDate(startDateForFirstObject.getDate() + 1);
                });
```